# Fullpage.js - Dot Navigation Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to style the dot navigation for Fullpage.JS however I'm having some trouble.

Here's a fiddle of my code and what i currently have:
https://jsfiddle.net/my9tqcho/

I'm trying to add the "fill up" effect, as seen [HERE](http://tympanus.net/Development/DotNavigationStyles/).

Here's the source code for the effect:

```
.dotstyle ul {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.dotstyle li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 16px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dotstyle li a {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-indent: -999em;
    cursor: pointer; /* make the text accessible to screen readers */
    position: absolute;
}

/* Fill up */
.dotstyle-fillup li a {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    transition: background 0.3s;
}

.dotstyle-fillup li a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}

.dotstyle-fillup li a:hover,
.dotstyle-fillup li a:focus {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dotstyle-fillup li.current a::after {
    height: 100%;
}
```

So far I found [THIS](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/199) answer from the creator of fullpage.js, but I seem to miss something and I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Just in case you are interested, there are [similar effects available to buy](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/#navigation) in fullPage. The "filled circles" one is very similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a fork of your jsfiddle and got it to work here https://jsfiddle.net/6z67g7v6/

What you want to do is to set `overflow: hidden` and `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white` so that it allows for such 'filled' effect.

The pseudo element styling is like the source code.

Cheers.